# POST request to REST WebMethod is giving 404 error

Tags: wcf, rest

Regarding REST service POST request, below are the code blocks I have written but it is not working and 404 error is coming.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:52811/FetchRecipe.svc/GetRecipe/5");
        oRequest.Method = "POST";
        oRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        string strRequest = "{'iRecipeId':'5'}";
        oRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;
        MemoryStream mo = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strRequest));
        using (Stream sr = oRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            mo.CopyTo(sr);
            sr.Close();
        }

        oResponse = (HttpWebResponse)oRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream oResponseStream = oResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(oResponseStream);
        string sResponse = sr1.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

WCF Contract Interface

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/GetRecipe")]
    List<RecipeModal> GetRecipe(string iRecipeId);
```

Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
public class RecipeModal
{
    [DataMember]
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string RecipeTitle { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Servings { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int ReadyTime { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your operation contract to the following,in order to map the url parameter to the function parameter:

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetRecipe/{iRecipeId}")]
 List<RecipeModal> GetRecipe(string iRecipeId);
```

Comment: Apply your suggestion, it works. But then there won't be any use of
`oRequest.Method = "POST";
        oRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

        string strRequest = "{'iRecipeId':'5'}";
        oRequest.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;
        MemoryStream mo = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strRequest));
        using (Stream sr = oRequest.GetRequestStream())
        {
            mo.CopyTo(sr);
            sr.Close();
        }`

I basically want to POST some data not in URL but with request body. Please suggest.

Comment: then try removing the /5 at the end of : oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:52811/FetchRecipe.svc/GetRecipe/5");

Comment: Tried with removing "5", 404 error. Tried removing 5 and {RecipeId}, 400 (Bad Request) error came.

Comment: Did you remove /5 from the url, /{iRecipeId} from uriTemplate and string iRecipeId from the method signature?

Comment: I don't think removing "string iRecipeId" is required. I am expecting the POST data matches the operation function arguments. So if we have 2 arguments say x and y in the operation function and POST data will have {"x":"3","y":"4"}, then, in function x will be 3 and y will be 4 by default without writing any specific code. Please provide an explaination if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: No it doesn't work this way. You are now posting a stream of data and should include in your method only a Stream variable. Then it would be up to you to break the stream to key value pairs. The easy way to do this would be as i proposed. Have methods waiting the variables you want and using the contract metadata map them to your request. Then call the service like test/method/x/y . Then you would have the data available in your method. Can you try this?